# Can media queries be used along with jquery mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I'm just reading up on how to develop sites with responsive layouts. I think I've grasped the idea and can now style content differently, depending on browser dimensions.

However I've also looked into Jquery mobile and I like the UI that they use.

My question is, is it possible to combine the two? ie. Could I have a web page that renders normally when viewed on a pc/mac, but when the browser width drops sub 320px (for example), could I switch over to using Jquery mobile?

I thought this'd be possible by including the jquery mobile scripts in my page, along with the 'data role' attributes, but only including the jquery mobile stylesheet if the browser is a particular size, ie:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

Is this at all possible? I can't tell whether I'm trying to use Jquery mobile for something it's not designed to deal with? Should I just have an entirely separate site ie. http://m.mysite.com that has standalone mobile content? Or is it possible to have an adaptive website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes jQM Supports Media queries:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html (Grade A)
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/mediahelpers.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Answer (score 1):

that is a very interesting question...

The answer depends on factors like how differnt the 2 designs are like one below 320px and other above that..

If the difference is huge, having a separate mobile website is a good idea..

But if the difference is minimal, you can just handle that with the CSS Media Queries.

You can combine the CSS Media Queries with Responsive Web Design to handle different sized screens..

Comment: Well my chief concern about having a separate site is having to mirror the content. Although I suppose we'd only be creating a second site IF the two sites were so very different and would have different content anyway.

I suppose in the situations I'm talking about, I want the content to be the same, I'd just like to render it differently for different devices.. in which case I think you're right, media queries are the way to go. I just wanted to use the JQuery mobile UI!

Comment: Yes right...Media Queries should be the preferred way for targetting different screen sizes..need to maintain only the CSS in that case...As for the other part, u can consider Sencha touch, Flowplayer, jQTouch apart from jQuery Mobile as well...

Answer (score 1):

The question was not really answered as it was asked.

You cannot use JQM only on the mobile site and not on the desktop verion using only CSS media queries. You'd have to do completely separate sites and do a redirect.

A possibly better option is to use JQM on both mobile and desktop version, in which case CSS media queries work perfectly. The problem with doing that is it limits both how you can use JQM and how you design your site. You really can't take an existing modern desktop design and make it JQM.

The JQM demo itself uses media queries to turn it into a two column layout on desktop and tablet sized browsers, and single column on phones. Issues with doing it that way: the entire page acts like a page, meaning divs such as side menus transition and reload with a new page (which is why they only use the fade transition).  Normal AJAX loading of content that doesn't involve the whole page will need to either be made to involve the whole page, or done custom outside the normal JQM way of doing things. Might not be too hard in some cases but it will up the JS code and make certain applications much more complicated. I can also see the CSS getting quickly out of hand for designs that are more complicated than the JQM demo.